# Purpose of using union within structure in c

Tags: c

```
typedef struct
{
  int k;
  union
  {
    int i;
    int j;
  }use;

}std;
```

Directly we can use the variable i and j in structure why it is used within union.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, i.e.

```
typedef struct
{
  int k;
  union
  {
    int i;
    int j;
  }use;

}std;
```

it doesn't seem to make much sense as `i` and `j` are the same type and the names of the variables isn't that descriptive.

It can make sense to have the same type for union elements if that would make the code easier to write, read, understand and maintain. Example:

```
...
union
{  
    int numberOfCars;
    int numberOfBicycles;
}use;
...
```

When writing code for handling `cars` you could use `numberOfCars` and when writing code for handling `bicycles` you could use `numberOfBicycles`. In this way the code would be easier to understand/maintain and the two code blocks could still share a common structure.

In one code block you could have:

```
std carDealer;
carDealer.use.numberOfCars = 9;
```

and in another code block (other file perhaps), you could have:

```
std bicyclesDealer;
bicyclesDealer.use.numberOfBicycles = 9;
```

A more typical case for unions is that the elements are of different type.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we wish to store information about employees in an organization.
Name Grade Age

```
If grade=HSK(Highly skilled)
hobby name
credit card number
If Grade=SSK(Semi skilled)
Vehicle no.
Distance from Company
```

We can use a single structure for it but then it would lead to wastage of memory coz either hobby name & credit card no. or vehicle no. & distance from com. is used at a time. Both of them are never used simultaneously. So, here union inside structure can be used effectively:

Code:

```
struct info1
{
char hobby[10];
int crcardno;
};
struct info2
{
char vehno[10];
int dist;
};
union info
{
struct info1 a;
struct info2 b;
};
struct emp
{
char n[20];
char grade[4];
int age;
union info f;
};
struct emp e;
```

HOPE YOU UNDERSTAND.......

Source : http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/122228-union-inside-structure.html